# sql update statement where 2 condition apllies

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

This is quite a basic question, but have not found that much on-line to support.
I need to use a simple update statement in mysql (I know i should use mysqli but not yet ready for this update)

Given That I am working with a database made of a fixed number of items I want that the update apllies only when 2 conditions together are true.

my idea is something like

```
$sql ="update `members` set `description`='$description[$index]' WHERE id='1' AND fruit = 'banana'";
```

Is this the proper way of selecting the record to be updated?

Many thanks
Manu

Comment: if your string contains a value (aka is not going to return an error) it should work... and yes, it is a proper way.

Comment: looks good, also you can add more `AND's` if needed

Comment: Minor point by convention id in a table is unique.

Comment: Actually... all of you are correct I will not use id as parameter to select the record (it would return just one of them). I will just use two other parameters that are not unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that should work but it's safer to wrap array values in a string in brackets:

```
$sql ="UPDATE `members` SET `description`='{$description[$index]}' WHERE id='1' AND fruit = 'banana'";
```

Also make sure $description is somehow filtered or validated, before plugging it directly into the string.
NOTE: Best practice dictates that you use all caps for all SQL keywords, allowing easier differentiation between keywords and your values. Yours has half and half update and set lowercase; WHERE and AND caps, which is worse than going with all lowercase.

[edit] I agree with Daniel Saad that you should be using prepared statements here as well.

Answer (score 3):

That's how you'd do it more or less, here's a refined one:

```
$sql ="update `members` set `description`=? WHERE `id`='1' AND `fruit` = 'banana'";
```

1) See how I put the ? instead of the array? There are smart objects in PHP (read about "Prepared Statements") which allow you to put a parameter "spot" in the query and later have a value instead of it. This makes your query much more secure.

2) I added '`' around your columns. It's not mandatory, but it makes sure that your columns aren't mistaken for something else.

Comment: thanks very much, I will have a read to the Prepared statement, for now given my lack of experience I prefer to not add any other sophistication to my site, I will in the future

Comment: Don't quote the placeholder, that makes it literal. http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php Should be `\`description\`= ? ...`

Comment: My bad. Edited the post. :)